# How to add HostnameVerifier to ktor client using okhttp engine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

Im trying to add the HostnameVerifier

`HostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }`

to my kotlin multiplatform ktor client and I couldn't be able to understand how to do that:

```kotlin
  @KtorExperimentalAPI actual val httpClient = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
     engine {
         // how to set HostnameVerifier?

         val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
         loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
         addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like that:

```kotlin
actual val httpClient = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    engine {
        // https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html
        config { // this: OkHttpClient.Builder ->
            // ...
            hostnameVerifier {
                    _, _ -> true
            }
        }

        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)

    }
}
```